# Data driven selenium automation using apache poi with jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, apache-poi

Currently I  am using excel as an input for my selenium web driver scripts(run via eclipse).I am planning to integrate these automated test cases to Jenkins. Is there any way we can use excel input for selenium tests which are integrated with Jenkins

Comment: first make your test case data driven with poi and then make it a jenkins project

Comment: Thanks much ! The test cases are already data drivened using apache poi.
My problem is how do we refer the excel(input data) to selenium tests in jenkins. Is there any tutorial for this ?

Comment: it will be useful to recognize your question ,if you post your code

Comment: keep excel sheet inside the project and simply call it form jenkins it will work

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do it like below also please note answer to this question is little bit lengthy ,also i have kept my self very simple and basic

1.sample logic to read .XLSX file

```
public class ExcelReader {
    public String ExcelReaderSample() throws IOException{
        String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\rajnish\\workspace\\googleExample\\src\\TestData.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
         while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                           // System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            return cell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
                    System.out.print(" - ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            workbook.close();
            inputStream.close();
            return null;
    }
}
```

2.Sample test in which we will use data taken form excel sheet

```
 public class SampleExample {
    @Test
    public void SampleRun() throws IOException {
        // opening Firefox Browser
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Reading Excel sheet
        ExcelReader excelReader = new ExcelReader();
        String keywordToSearch = excelReader.ExcelReaderSample();
        // Searching they keyword fetched from Excel sheet
        System.out.println("This is the keyword that i want to search : " + keywordToSearch);
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(keywordToSearch);
    }
}
```

**Note** -talking under consideration that you have latest apache poi imported in your project

3.Now keep your file structure like below (keep your excel file inside the project from where you want to read data )

4. Now install jenkins from here https://jenkins.io/ (note i am on windows)
5. Run **jenkins.war** from command prompt (mine is at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war) java -jar jenkins.war

Now type localHost:8080 (default port) in your favorite browser

Configure Project With Jenkins
1.Click on New Item

2.Select Freestyle project

3.Give a name to your project "SampleExampleForJenkins"

4.Click Save and select Back to Dashboard

5. Select Manage Jenkins then Configure System

6.under JDK give JAVA_HOME and click apply and then save

For simple java project run configuration of jenkins is done.

**Please note i have used TESTNG** and my project structure is like this

Sample excel data
[image]

sample project structure
[image]

1. Now go to the project location and create a Lib folder and keep all jars file inside it

   a.Selenium all jars
   b.selenium server.jar
   c.apache poi all jars

Now create a batch file 
as per this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e8I3A49ERc at 15:00

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Can we give excel file in the project tree .. Will jenkins consider taking input from the excel sheet which is in project folder ?
Thanks again!!

Comment: In the code snippet above excel file path(excelFilePath )  is specified, is it feasible to give the file path and integrate with jenkins?